SSL error unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled in python3
Hitting SSL error.
requests.get("xxxx", verify=False) 

Error
SSL error unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled when using requests in python3. 

Tried to downgrade the openssl version and switched to python3.10 nothing worked.

That must be a truly ancient server you are trying to connect to. OpenSSL rejection of 'legacy' renegotiation dates to 0.9.8l in 2009, even before rfc5746 was officially published. It looks to me like you'll need to go back to python 3.0 (which I've heard was barely usable) or 2.6 (which is of course quite a different language and unlikely to support any code written for 3). If you can instead use urllib+ssl in 3.12 up, it claims to have an SSLContext option for this
